# Tensorflow Print doesn't print anything if exception is thrown during downstream operations

Tags: tensorflow

I noticed that Tensorflow tf.Print doesn't output anything if an exception occurs during the evaluation of the downstream operations(in the most interesting cases!). Is there the way to make Print print out data immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but try using `tf.Assert()` to catch the problem before it results in the exception.

`tf.Assert(condition, data, summarize=None, name=None)`

- condition: The condition to evaluate.
- data: The tensors to print out when condition is false.
- summarize: Print this many entries of each tensor.
- name: A name for this operation (optional).

Refs:

1. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Assert